# How to confirm the WindowsPhone-Development-Tools' contract that is installed on SurfacePro

Tags: eula, windows-phone-toolkit

I installed the WindowsPhone development's environment on SurfacePro from

- -> http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
- ->  Windows Phone 8.1 development tools
- -> If you don’t have Visual Studio 2013, you can install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows, which includes Update 2, using this download link:
- -> Download(up to 1.1 MB, English)

However, I forgot to read carefully this tool's contract which is displayed on screen when I was installing it.
Please tell me how to reconfirm the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express will not install without accepting the license agreement

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to accept the license agreement before installing.     I want to know how to "reconfirm" the license after installing.

Comment: You can view the license agreement again if you go to the help menu and select about you will see a link to view the license agreement in the top right corner of the dialog that opens